# Is it possible to promote a lambda expression to an instance method?

Tags: java, serialization, lambda

I have a functional interface:

```java
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ITransform<I, O> extends Serializable {

    O process(I input);

    static <I, O> ITransform<I, O> of(ITransform<I, O> source) {
        return source;
    }
}
```

With an abstract implementation:

```java
public abstract class Transform implements ITransform<IOvariable, IOvariable> {

    protected final Class<?> inputClass;

    public Transform(Class<?> inputClass) {
        this.inputClass = inputClass;
    }

    public Class<?> getInputClass() {
        return inputClass;
    }
}
```

And a sample concrete implementation:

```
public class ConcreteTransform extends Transform {

    public ConcreteTransform() {
        super(SampleObject.class);
    }

    @Override
    public IOvariable process(IOvariable input) {
        Class<?> inputClass = input.getClazz();
        if (inputClass == this.inputClass) {
            return IOvariable.create(((SampleObject) input.getVariable()).getNumber());
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "Input is " + input.getClazz()
                + " but this transform requires " + this.getInputClass());
    }
}
```

I have also created a `Pipeline` class which essentially strings together `ITransform` objects and executes them

```
    ITransform<IOvariable, IOvariable> transform = new ConcreteTransform();
    ITransform<String, Integer> parseInt = ITransform.of(Integer::parseInt);
    ITransform<Integer, Integer> timesTwo = ITransform.of(input -> input * 2);
    ITransform<Integer, String> toString = ITransform.of(Object::toString);
    ITransform<String, String> output = ITransform.of(input -> "The output is: " + input);

    Pipeline pipe = new Pipeline(new SampleObject("10"))
         .addTransform(transform)
         .addTransform(parseInt)
         .addTransform(timesTwo)
         .addTransform(toString)
         .addTransform(prettyOutput);

>>> "The output is: 20"
```

Now, the ultimate goal would be to serialize this pipeline so that it can be restored and reused elsewhere. However, all but the first transform in the above example are instantiated via lambda objects via the functional interface.

While it would be easy enough to serialize the first transform, I have read that it's in bad form to serialize lambda's.

This leads me to the question: **Is there any funky way to promote a functional interface like `ITransform` to a concrete implementation of `Transform` by making the lambda a fully-fledged method?**

That way, I could serialize the result without serializing a lambda expression.

Comment: No.  You will need to serialize the lambda.  You certainly can't turn it into a _different_ class which will serialize correctly.

Comment: (You _might_ be able to make a new class that executes the lambda, but you certainly can't make something that will serialize in a way that can be rebuilt at the other end.)